# how to add html with document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I need half and sleeve(dt, dd) display one line, and color, design is each lines.

so I want add html(hr) after second dd, but not working

and I working with woocommerce, so I want to edit it in the admin panel(editing pages menu) where possible.

can I get the solution?

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName('variation-item')[1].innerHTML = '<hr/>';
}
</script>

<dl class="variation">
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">half:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_S"><p>01_S</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">sleeve:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_S"><p>01_S</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">color:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_NONE"><p>01_NONE</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">design:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-02_DESIGN"><p>02_DESIGN</p></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML = ...` doesn't _add_ but overwrites the content of the modified element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
Object.prototype.insertAfter = function (newNode) {
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, this.nextSibling);
}

var nodeToInsert = document.createElement("hr");
document.getElementsByClassName('variation-item')[1].insertAfter(nodeToInsert);
```

```html
<dl class="variation">
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">half:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_S"><p>01_S</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">sleeve:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_S"><p>01_S</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">color:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_NONE"><p>01_NONE</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">design:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-02_DESIGN"><p>02_DESIGN</p></dd>
</dl>
```

[Javascript insertAfter()](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2009/08/javascript-insertafter/)

> There is no Node.insertAfter() DOM function in Javascript, but it is clearly something that developers would like.

You can also check [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) with `afterend` position

```js
var hr = document.createElement("hr");
document.getElementsByClassName('variation-item')[1].insertAdjacentElement('afterend', hr);
```

```html
<dl class="variation">
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">half:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_S"><p>01_S</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">sleeve:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_S"><p>01_S</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">color:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-01_NONE"><p>01_NONE</p></dd>
    <dt class="variation- variation-title">design:</dt>
    <dd class="variation- variation-item variation-02_DESIGN"><p>02_DESIGN</p></dd>
</dl>
```